# x86 example code. 'Programming from the Gound Up'

Tags: x86

I'm trying to learn more about assembly programming. I'm following the book 'Programming from the Ground Up'. I'm having trouble with the second example program. I've been troubleshooting it and have also checked online for any posted errata.

The program is designed to output the highest of the listed numbers. This list is marked under data_items. After being run in the terminal the program should do nothing. However it should return 222 (the highest number in the list) after you enter echo $?. Currently it returns 3 or the first number.

I don't think the following are issues

-The inc statement has to be working or it would be stuck in an infinite loop as it would never reach the 0 to exit the loop

-I thought it could be an issue with the .long and the 4 in the mov statements in a 64 bit environment however I did tried substituting 8 for the 4 and no luck.

-In addition to the above statement I don't think it's a general 64 bit vs 32 bit issue as I have looked that up here and the consensus seems to be that 32 bit programs will run fine on 64 bit and I have tried the one specific issue I thought may have come up.

I'm thinking the problems could be with the second cmp statement between the ebx and eax registers.

Thank you in advance and sorry if any or all of my assumptions above are wrong I just wanted you guys to know what I had tried, researched, and where my thought process was.

The code is as follows below.

```
#PURPOSE:       This program finds the maximum number of a
#           set of data items.
#

#VARIABLES:     The registers have the following uses:
#
# %edi - Holds the index of the data item being examined
# %ebx - Largest data item found
# %eax - Current data item
#
# The following memory locations are used:
#
# data_items - contains the item data. A 0 is used 
#          to terminate the data
#

.section .data

data_items:     #These are the data items
 .long 3,67,34,222,45,75,54,34,44,33,22,11,66,0

 .section .text

 .globl _start
_start:
 movl $0, %edi              # move 0 into the index register
 movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax     # load the first byte of data
 movl %eax, %ebx                # since this is the first item, 
                    # %eax is the biggest


start_loop:                 # start loop
 cmpl $0, %eax                  # check to see if we've hit theend
 je loop_exit               # if so uncondition jmp to exit
 incl %edi                  # load next value
 movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
 cmpl %ebx, %eax                    # compare values
 jle start_loop             # jump to loop beginning

 loop_exit:
  # %ebx is the return value, and it has the highest number availible
    movl $1, %eax           #1 is the exit() syscall
    int $0x80
```

Comment: You move a value into %ebx only once (the first item).  Perhaps you should have a "movl  %eax, %ebx" followed by a "jmp start_loop" after "jle start_loop"?

Comment: Just saw your comment. Looks like I missed it in the tutorial, I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure out what was wrong and looking for typos. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this book, but is it possible that it deliberately gives you buggy example code and you're supposed to find the bugs for yourself?  That is a common pedagogical tactic. (I'm not convinced it's a *good* pedagogical tactic.)

Comment: No I just checked. I flat out missed it. I think it's one of those things were when you look at something too many times where your eyes glaze over and you're not really seeing it any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the only statement in the entire program that writes to `%ebx`:

```
movl %eax, %ebx        # since this is the first item, 
                       # %eax is the biggest
```

The loop runs until `%ebx` is less than `%eax`, and then it immediately exits, with `%ebx` equal to the first value in the array, namely 3.

If I add two more lines immediately after `jle start_loop`, namely

```
movl %eax, %ebx  # copy new largest value to %ebx
jmp start_loop   # and continue
```

then the program executes as expected (when compiled with `gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -m32 test.s`).

It would be *better* to write this program like this:

```
    .section .rodata
data_items:
    .long 3,67,34,222,45,75,54,34,44,33,22,11,66,0
    .section .text
    .globl main
main:
    xorl  %ecx, %ecx
    movl  data_items(,%ecx,4), %edx
    movl  %edx, %eax
loop:
    # data_items assumed to have at least two elements
    cmpl  %eax, %edx
    cmovg %edx, %eax
    incl  %ecx
    movl  data_items(,%ecx,4), %edx
    testl %edx, %edx
    jne loop
    # return the largest value, which is in %eax
    ret
```

In addition to some minor micro-optimizations, I have made the program ABI-compliant, changed its entry point from `_start` to `main` so the C library has a chance to initialize, and I return from `main` (which causes a call to `exit`) instead of open-coding the `_exit` system call.

ABI compliance in this case is a matter of using the correct registers.  I return from `main`, so I have to satisfy the expectations of the code that *calls* `main`, in particular, that when `main` returns, `%ebx`, `%esi`, `%edi`, and `%ebp` will still have the same values that they did before the function call.  If you use any of those registers you are responsible for pushing their old values on the stack on entry, and popping them off again on exit.  Since this code needs only three registers and doesn't itself make any function calls, it is best to use only `%eax`, `%ecx`, and `%edx`, which are *not* required to retain their old values after a function call.  Your book probably explains this at some point.

(The 64-bit ABI's register usage rules are more complicated, because it passes parameters in registers, and I don't have them memorized.)

Despite any number of guides and tutorials that tell you the opposite, *you should never open-code system calls*.  Call the wrappers in the C library, or in this case, return from `main`.  The C library is there to insulate you from low-level ABI glorp that you don't want to have to deal with -- for instance, it will always use the most efficient possible trap sequence, it knows the *correct* system call numbers (I recall a question a few years ago whose answer boiled down to "`_exit` is not system call #1 in the 64-bit ABI"), and it knows how to set `errno`.

Comment: Wow, don't believe I didn't catch that. I'm gonna experiment with the rewrite you posted. It may have been written the way it was to be easier for a beginner. Which didn't help too much. Thank you for the help.

Comment: At that point in the book (which is very early), there had been no mention of library functions and such. The only mechanism for passing values out of a program is to call the `exit` primitive, and read the exit code as if it was the value returned by the program. That's why the "return value" is placed in `%ebx`. The book **should**, but does not (at least up to that point), say that using the exit code to return values is a gross abuse of the system, and it's done only for a short time for teaching purposes, and should be forgotten quickly.

Comment: @mathguy Yeah, so if I had written the book I might have started it off the same way, except that I would be returning from `main` instead of attempting to open-code the exit syscall. Perhaps they were trying to avoid the C library altogether, but IMNSHO that just adds distracting complications.

Comment: Discussion of the "library" concept, and the C library in particular, is several chapters later in the book. I don't mind how the book is structured (learning from it right now!) except for what I said - explaining beforehand that some of the practices shown are purely for teaching purposes and should be forgotten once "we" learn enough to be able to do things the right way.